# Helenus throwing Exception

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql, helenus

I am trying to connect Node.js(using Express) with Cassandra CQL using Helenus.

I have created the keyspace in CQL and installed Helenus but I am getting the exception shown below:

```
D:\Test\node_modules\helenus\node_modules\helenus-thrift\lib\thrift\connection.js:90  
    throw e;  
HelenusNoAvailableNodesException: Could Not Connect To Any Nodes
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is C* on? Check if you have networking access to the server by using telnet <ip> <port> eg:`telnet localhost 9160`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Lyuben.
I have tried using telnet and its working fine but still getting the helenus exception.

Comment: I am getting same exception during connecting the helenus.